# how to hide the list when the input box is blank in Filter/Search List

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I am trying to create a filter/search list, knowing that I want to hide the list until the user tries to type and hide it when the user deletes all the characters in the field of (myInput)

these are the two tags input (myInput) and the list (mylist)

```html
<input id="myInput" type="search" placeholder="type to search" />
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

This the jquery code, $("#myList") is hidden in the loading page until the user starts typing but what if the user removes all characters in the box how can I hide the list again?

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myList li").filter(function() {
    $("#myList").show();
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just set a simple condition for it using the [event interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) or the actual value that you trying to set you can do either of them, but in my opinion *(Because it will prevent to create an unnecessary jQuery element like `$(this)`)*, using the event will be more efficient. So whenever the input value has something you go for running the filter function otherwise you will hide anything.

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.target.value) {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $("#myList").show();
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  } else {
    $("#myList").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#myList {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="search" placeholder="type to search" />
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (value.length) {
      $("#myList li").filter(function() {
        $("#myList").show();
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    } else {
      $("#myList").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="search" placeholder="type to search" />
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```